# Kafka Connect in timestamp mode never stops reading

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am building a Kafka Connector to a SQL Server database in timestamp mode and it's already reading and transforming data but it never stops reading. Once it reaches the last row of the table it starts again.
The input database has a column called `date` that I use as the incrementing column.

Here is the properties file

```
name=total_memory

connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx;databaseName=xxx
connection.password=1234
connection.user=user

tasks.max=1
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=test
time.precision.mode=connect
topic.prefix=total_memory

incrementing.column.name=date
mode=timestamp

query=SELECT node_id, date, total_memory, status, metric_id FROM details ORDER BY date ASC

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

transforms=castStringToInt,TimestampConverter

transforms.castStringToInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value
transforms.castStringToInt.spec=node_id:int16,total_memory:float32,metric_id:int8

transforms.TimestampConverter.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
transforms.TimestampConverter.field=date
transforms.TimestampConverter.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type=string
transforms.TimestampConverter.unix.precision=seconds
```

Any clue? Thanks